# Inserting elements to an xml file from another xml file

Tags: xml, merge

I have two xml files and i need to merge that xml files based on XMLElements.

first xml looks like

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="test" value="value"/>
        <add key="test1" value="value1"/>
    </appSettings>
   </configuration>
```

second xml looks like

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="test2" value="value2"/>
        <add key="test3" value="value3"/>
    </appSettings>
   </configuration>
```

And output should be:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="test" value="value"/>
        <add key="test1" value="value1"/>
        <add key="test2" value="value2"/>
        <add key="test3" value="value3"/>
    </appSettings>
   </configuration>
```

Please give an sample code to do this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this in the following way by using Dataset.

```
DataSet firstSet = new DataSet();
firstSet.ReadXml("first.xml");

DataSet secondSet = new DataSet();
secondSet.ReadXml("second.xml");

firstSet.Merge(secondSet);

firstSet.WriteXml("output.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

[Linq to xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)
will help to solve your problem